# Directx 9 Normal Mapping Pixelshader

Tags: directx, pixel-shader

I have a question about normal mapping in directx9 shader.
Currently my Terrain shader Output for Normal Map + Diffuse Color only result into this Image.
Which looks good to me.

[image: Normal Map + Diffuse Color]

If i use an empty Normal map image like this one.

[image]

My shader output for normal diffuse and color map looks like this.
[image]

But if i use [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ8gH.png) including a ColorMap i get a really stange result.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this issue?

Here is some snippets.

```
float4 PS_TERRAIN(VSTERRAIN_OUTPUT In) : COLOR0
{
    float4 fDiffuseColor;
    float lightIntensity;
    
    float3 bumpMap = 2.0f * tex2D( Samp_Bump, In.Tex.xy ).xyz-1.0f;
    float3 bumpNormal = (bumpMap.x * In.Tangent) + (bumpMap.y * In.Bitangent) + (bumpMap.z * In.Normal);
    bumpNormal = normalize(bumpNormal);

    // Direction Light Test ( Test hardcoded )
    float3 lightDirection = float3(0.0f, -0.5f, -0.2f);
    float3 lightDir = -lightDirection;

    // Bump
    lightIntensity = saturate(dot( bumpNormal, lightDir)); 

    // We are using a lightmap to do our alpha calculation for given pixel
    float4 LightMaptest = tex2D( Samp_Lightmap, In.Tex.zw ) * 2.0f;
    fDiffuseColor.a = LightMaptest.a;
    if( !bAlpha )
        fDiffuseColor.a = 1.0;
    
    // Sample the pixel color from the texture using the sampler at this texture coordinate location.
    float4 textureColor = tex2D( Samp_Diffuse, In.Tex.xy );

    // Combine the color map value into the texture color.
    textureColor = saturate(textureColor * LightMaptest);
    textureColor.a = LightMaptest.a;
    
    fDiffuseColor.rgb = saturate(lightIntensity * I_d).rgb;
    fDiffuseColor = fDiffuseColor * textureColor; // If i enable this line it goes crazy
    return fDiffuseColor;
}
```